# Is it possible to create a meeting request for outlook with nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, calendar, outlook

I am developing a very basic calendar with Angular and Node and I haven't found any code on this.

Workflow is the following : create an event, input the recipient's e-mail address, validate the event. 
This triggers an e-mail sent to the recipient. The mail should be in the outlook meeting request format (not an attached object).

This means that when received in outlook the meeting is automatically added in the calendar.

Is this possible? If yes is it possible with only javascript on Node side?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For those still looking for an answer, here's how I managed to get the perfect solution for me.
I used iCalToolkit to create a calendar object.

It's important to make sure all the relevant fields are set up (organizer and attendees with RSVP).

Initially I was using the Postmark API service to send my emails but this solution was only working by sending an ics.file attachment.

I switched to the Postmark SMTP service where you can embed the iCal data inside the message and for that I used nodemailer.

This is what it looks like :

```
        var icalToolkit = require('ical-toolkit');
        var postmark = require('postmark');
        var client = new postmark.Client('xxxxxxxKeyxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
        var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

        //Create a iCal object
        var builder = icalToolkit.createIcsFileBuilder();
        builder.method = meeting.method;
        //Add the event data

        var icsFileContent = builder.toString();
        var smtpOptions = {
            host:'smtp.postmarkapp.com',
            port: 2525,
            secureConnection: true,
            auth:{
               user:'xxxxxxxKeyxxxxxxxxxxxx',
               pass:'xxxxxxxPassxxxxxxxxxxx'
            }
        };

        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport(smtpOptions));

        var mailOptions = {
            from: 'message@domain.com',
            to: meeting.events[0].attendees[i].email,
            subject: 'Meeting to attend',
            html: "Anything here",
            text: "Anything here",
            alternatives: [{
              contentType: 'text/calendar; charset="utf-8"; method=REQUEST',
              content: icsFileContent.toString()
            }]
        };

        //send mail with defined transport object 
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
            else{
                console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);  
            }
        });
```

This sends a real meeting request with the Accept, decline and Reject button.

It's really unbelievable the amount of work you need to go through for such a trivial functionality and how all of this not well documented.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey i am using express framework for creating an outlook calender even when i used your functionality i am getting error as meeting not defined in line:builder.method = meeting.method;
could you please help me with this..

Comment: meeting is the object that contains all the calendar event information (prperties :method, events. Inside events you have start, end, organizer, attendees, etc)

Comment: You need to create this object before. This part is not in the code I posted. It's simply var meeting = {method:..., events[...]}, check out the icalToolkit doc to see the content of the .... parts.

Comment: and what should i define in service when i use var smtpOptions = {
           service:
            secureConnection: true,
            auth:{
               user:'xxxxxxxKeyxxxxxxxxxxxx',
               pass:'xxxxxxxPassxxxxxxxxxxx'
            }
        };
because i need to send it to the outlook and i had seen other codes where people define service:gmail like such

Comment: For this you need some mail service provider. I use postmark but there are other possibilities. They provide theses credentials to send mail through smtp. Usually it is explained in the doc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116900/discussion-between-shikha-thakur-and-vonwolf).

Comment: Hi, I didn't quite get why you need to use smtp?  Isn't it enough to send the ical file as an attachment, or does it require the user to open the attachment manually?  I also like to handle the meeting responses, assumedly inbound to postmark, do you know/have any resources on how to do that?

Comment: I tried using the API but in my experience it's just a normal file attatchement and therefore doesn't display the accept/tentative/decline buttons. To have them you need to embed the ical information as alternatives and not attachements. With postmark this can only be done with SMTP. To manage responses you can configure this in Settings > Inbound > Webhook. The details are explained in the docs.

Comment: I have tried the same code with mandrill and its not working. It should be working with mandrill as well right ?

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want to use smtp server approach in earlier accepted solution, you have Exchange focused solution available. Whats wrong in current accepted answer? it does not create a meeting in sender's Calendar, you do not have ownership of the meeting item for further modification by the sender Outlook/OWA.

here is code snippet in javascript using npm package `ews-javascript-api`

```js
var ews = require("ews-javascript-api");
var credentials = require("../credentials");
ews.EwsLogging.DebugLogEnabled = false;

var exch = new ews.ExchangeService(ews.ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);

exch.Credentials = new ews.ExchangeCredentials(credentials.userName, credentials.password);

exch.Url = new ews.Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/Ews/Exchange.asmx");

var appointment = new ews.Appointment(exch);

appointment.Subject = "Dentist Appointment";
appointment.Body = new ews.TextBody("The appointment is with Dr. Smith.");
appointment.Start = new ews.DateTime("20170502T130000");
appointment.End = appointment.Start.Add(1, "h");
appointment.Location = "Conf Room";
appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("user1@constoso.com");
appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("user2@constoso.com");
appointment.OptionalAttendees.Add("user3@constoso.com");

appointment.Save(ews.SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy).then(function () {
    console.log("done - check email");
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Accepted solution has nothing wrong, it's just a different approach which answered the question. Question did not require to have ownership as modifications/updates are managed through the application which is the "master".

Comment: What is the information you require in credentials? Is it an exchange account login/pwd?

Comment: This needs Exchange username and password. 
I would not go into right or wrong discussion, to me (having Exchange experience) sending a crafted message has issues like appointment ownership, you can not modify the appointment after creating it this way. EWS solves the problem. obviously the package ews-javascript-api was in very early phase when this question was answered, now it can be used to overcome those issues by using another approach.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using 'ical-generator', I used 'ical-toolkit' to build a calender invite event.
Using this, the invite directly gets appended in the email instead of the attached .ics file object.

Here is a sample code:

```
const icalToolkit = require("ical-toolkit");

//Create a builder
var builder = icalToolkit.createIcsFileBuilder();
builder.method = "REQUEST"; // The method of the request that you want, could be REQUEST, PUBLISH, etc

//Add events
builder.events.push({
  start: new Date(2020, 09, 28, 10, 30),
  end: new Date(2020, 09, 28, 12, 30),
  timestamp: new Date(),
  summary: "My Event",
  uid: uuidv4(), // a random UUID
  categories: [{ name: "MEETING" }],
  attendees: [
    {
      rsvp: true,
      name: "Akarsh ****",
      email: "Akarsh **** <akarsh.***@abc.com>"
    },
    {
      rsvp: true,
      name: "**** RANA",
      email: "**** RANA <****.rana1@abc.com>"
    }
  ],
  organizer: {
    name: "A****a N****i",
    email: "A****a N****i <a****a.r.n****i@abc.com>"
  }
});

//Try to build
var icsFileContent = builder.toString();

//Check if there was an error (Only required if yu configured to return error, else error will be thrown.)
if (icsFileContent instanceof Error) {
  console.log("Returned Error, you can also configure to throw errors!");
  //handle error
}

var mailOptions = { // Set the values you want. In the alternative section, set the calender file
            from: obj.from,
            to: obj.to,
            cc: obj.cc,
            subject: result.email.subject,
            html: result.email.html,
            text: result.email.text,
            alternatives: [
              {
                contentType: 'text/calendar; charset="utf-8"; method=REQUEST',
                content: icsFileContent.toString()
              }
            ]
          }

        //send mail with defined transport object 
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
            else{
                console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);  
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible as long as you can use SOAP in Node and also if you can use NTLM authentication for Exchange with Node. I believe there are modules for each.

I found this [blog](https://www.howtoforge.com/talking-soap-with-exchange) very helpful when designing a similar system using PHP

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Before I do that I will try my luck with a plugin called node-icalendar.

Comment: If you're counting on Outlook to work well with subscribed internet calendars, prepare to be disappointed, I went down that road and it learned that Outlook is not very consistent about refreshing the calendar even when instructed to by either the calendar or manually.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following sample:

```js
const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

const onlineMeeting = {
  startDateTime: '2019-07-12T14:30:34.2444915-07:00',
  endDateTime: '2019-07-12T15:00:34.2464912-07:00',
  subject: 'User Token Meeting'
};

await client.api('/me/onlineMeetings')
    .post(onlineMeeting);
```

More Information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.